# Error in combine_vars(vars, ind_list) : Position must be between 0 and n in R

Tags: r

I am trying to pull a `csv` file for a cricket Analysis.

I am new to R.

I am getting the following error when I try to select it.

Code I wrote:

```
T1<- read.csv("JigT.csv",header = TRUE,sep = ",")
T1$Runs.Scored
```

When I run the above command I am able to get the output but when I run the below command

```
dplyr::select_(T1,T1$Runs.Scored)
```

It throws an error:

```
"Error in combine_vars(vars, ind_list) : 
  Each argument must yield either positive or negative integers
In addition: Warning message:Truncating vector to length 1 "
```

When i type the another command 
x<-dplyr::select(T1,T1$Runs.Scored)
I get the error "Error in combine_vars(vars, ind_list) : Position must be between 0 and n"

Also the columns when I type `T1$Runs.scored` , `T1$Venue` , the result works well but when I put it inside `select()` the columns are inter change ..for e.g. `T1$Runs.scored` becomes `T1$Bat`, `T1$bat` becomes `T1%Matchid` .

Please kindly advise me on this issue.

Comment: Please make your questtion better readable by [formatting your code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189). Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps what you want is `dplyr::select(T1, Runs.Scored)`. To select a column you pass the column name into the `select` function.

Comment: Thanks  Wong for your answer. Sorry werner .It was my first post in stacker flow. I will correct hereafter